# How I can host Media files like mp3 in a diffrent server?

Tags: php, media-queries, hosting, media, server

*How I can host Media files like mp3 in a different server ?*
I have a website for converting videos to audio.
I want to host this audio files in a different server, but I want to keep the codein the first server.
**Is this possible?**
For example, if the user finished the conversion, he will be redirected to the other server.

http://example.com/.... ===> http://serv55.example.com/.....

Comment: Sure it is! What failed on your attempts to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is have the first server which does the processing copy the file onto the 2nd server once it's finished processing.

The best way to do this (depending on your setup) would probably be using ssh to copy the files.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php

Comment: Thanks  ;and if I want to send files to a hosting not a server (without FTP)